# SourceTree and remote branch and trunk

Tags: git, git-svn, atlassian-sourcetree

Situation: I have a clone of a git repo on a remote machine. Is it possible to somehow import this remote clone to SourceTree on my local machine? The code would never be on my local machine, I would only like to manage changes on my remote clone (pull/commit/push/check changes etc.).

Possible or not?

Tnx in advance!

**Edit 2018-03-26:** Maybe I was not clear enough - it is a web project and we are developing on server directly. Access to the code on the server is strictly via SSH. Code commiting is possible only with GIT, installed on the server and accessed via SSH.

I would like to use SourceTree or something similar installed locally to work with GIT installed on the server (not on my local machine) via SSH. I am not talking about GIT repository via SSH but about GIT instance via SSH.

Company's security policy restricts copying code locally - cloning code to my machine is not an option.

Tnx in advance!

Comment: You can use `rsync` to sync files in the remote clone
    `rsync -a username@remote_host:/home/username/dir1 place_to_sync_on_local_machine`

Comment: @yausername the OP doesn’t want the code locally.

Answer (score 0):

Haven't tried this but you may try to **mount** your remote directory as a drive and then try to import the remote git repository in **Sourcetree**

Comment: Good suggestion. The OP says they don’t want the code locally, but then proceeds to say that they’ll do the code edits there. —- I think the OP should clone the repo locally and do the work locally, and stop thinking git is svn.

Comment: Yes, I might be equating git with svn too much. Thank you all for suggestions.

Comment: Hey guys, I edited my question with additional explanation about what I would like to achieve. Please review the question and give some good advice. :)